# Ionic Capacitor Admob plugin loadAd null object reference

Tags: java, android, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic Capacitor app and i am using the [capacitor community ad plugin](https://github.com/capacitor-community/admob), but i am getting the following error in Android Studio:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
```

I am running the application on an android phone with the command `ionic capacitor run android -l --external`

This is how the error happens:

- the app opens on the Welcome page
- the app shows a banner ad
- i click the login button
- the app removes the banner ad
- the app navigates to the login page
- the app should show a banner ad, BUT the app crashes

Welcome page (login page has the same life cycle methods and calls):

```
ionViewWillLeave(): void {
  this.removeAd();
}

ionViewWillEnter(): void {
  this.showAd();
}

private async showAd(): Promise<void> {
  await this.admobService.showBanner();
}

private async removeAd(): Promise<void> {
  await this.admobService.removeBanner();
}
```

Admob service:

```
public async showBanner(): Promise<void> {
  AdMob.addListener(BannerAdPluginEvents.FailedToLoad, (info) => {
    //console.log(info);
  });

  const options: BannerAdOptions = {
    adId: 'hidden',
    adSize: BannerAdSize.BANNER,
    position: BannerAdPosition.TOP_CENTER,
    margin: 0,
    isTesting: true,
  };
  AdMob.showBanner(options);
}

public async removeBanner(): Promise<void> {
  await AdMob.removeBanner();
}
```

Admob service is provided in root, and maybe that could be the case? But i would not like to provide it in every page specifically

Answer (score 3):

Probably, the banner destroys while it trying to show.  You can try add a delay via `setTimeout` (a few seconds for check this idea) for `this.showAd();` call:

```
ionViewWillEnter(): void {
    setTimeout(() => { this.showAd(); }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: In my case, the app wasn't loading and now it does but still crashes after 3 seconds.
Also, there are these warnings that preceded the crash in the log.
`Unable to open '/data/user/0/com.example.app/cache/1689111357674.dm': No such file or directory
2023-10-05 14:34:09.883 15511-15511 ConnectionStatusConfig  com.example.app                      W  Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.CACHE`